# SQL different table or store as text in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a dilemma that i can't seem to put to rest.

On a page i have a list of objects. Each of those objects is a slider - like aribnb - https://www.airbnb.com/s/London--United-Kingdom?source=ds

In my DB where i store information about that object (it has other info except the slides), i'm thinking, it would be easiest to store the URL for all the slides as a block of text.

```
URL       | other_field
-----------------------
url1,url2 | other stuff
```

then handle it from there in either front end or backend by converting them into an array etc.

The second approach would be to create a separate table where i'd store each url and id of the object that url belongs to on a separate row

```
URL  | obj_ID
-------------
url1 | id1
url2 | id1
url3 | id2
.............
```

. I'd do a `group_concat( distinct X)` and it would return them to me as a block of text. I'd then do the same thing with splitting them up.

Long story short, do i store them as a field in the initial table or in a separate table, each being it's own row.
What would be the advantages and disadvantages to either approach? To me it seems easier to have them as text in the same table, but i'm inexperienced in this, so i need some advice.

EDIT: The final usable format will be a JSON with the slides being either an array, or a text to be split into an array at the appropriate time.

Comment: I would go wit the 2nd option. Tables are always better in my opinion then delimited thing that needs to be parsed later. I would say pro of table is Join and Where clause are extremely easy to control and fast, I see no con. Con to first way is you have to take time to handle the array every time. Example If you a person with multi phone numbers, would you want to store them all on one row or multi in a table?

Comment: @HolmesIV It's a special case, since i can't really see any situation where there would be a comma in there that would throw things off (those are URLs) - and the second approach makes the DB engine do more work, does it not?

Comment: I don't see why it would do more work, simple joins, inserts. There is also the matter of Indexing, which will work much better in the table form

Comment: @HolmesIV an extra join instead of no join is extra work, correct? So why go trough the trouble of doing that, when what gets returned is, at the end of the day a block of text - forgot to mention, the final format that is usable is a JSON containing all the info about that specific object, including the slides as text, to be split - unless the DB can return array in array (can it?). There's the valid point about the inserts being simpler i guess.

Comment: I threw the json tag on, I am not familiar with it, and don't want to mislead

Comment: @HolmesIV Thank you. As to my question, i'll sleep on it and see what other suggestions i get.

Comment: My 5c: Are you sure you want to use an RDBMS at all? I see no relations so far, so do you actually need a relational database?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner In this isolated example, not, but overall yes. This case  is just a thing that's been bugging me and of no crucial importance.. but i have a curious nature.

Comment: URL seems to be (part of) a primary key. Even when not, the first snippet violates 1NF: {url1,url2} is a repeating group, it is not *atomic*.

Comment: @wildplasser um.. big discussion there, but since i'm not a DB expert by any means - i just do this because there's no one else for this project - i'm trying to structure things logically in my head (at least).

Comment: You don't need to be an expert. Just make sure you understand  normalisation, *at least* upto 2NF. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is... it depends.  If you think of your URLS as simply notes in a block of text, then maybe it makes sense to just store them in one field.  Make sure that you set the field length large enough.

However, if you think you ever might need to treat a URL as a relational entity... then you need to go the second route.  What do I mean by that?  Well, what if in the future you need to add a requirement to store not only the URL but a short description of it?  Maybe you need to add an active date to tell when the last time that URL was checked to be valid.  Maybe you would like to be able to find objects that share a common URL.  I'm not saying that these should be your requirements; I'm saying that you don't know what future requirements will be.  If you're very certain that this is just a block of text and it will always be just a block of text, then sure... put it in a VARCHAR(MAX) field.  Down the road though as requirements are built on, you'll be tempted to try to hack more stuff into that blob of text, which will make things more difficult going forward.

Sometimes it's appropriate to break normal form for speed or simplicity, but you want to do it sparingly and with as much forethought into the future as possible.

Comment: Great answer. It got me thinking in the right direction. I was too focused on what's faster when i should have been focused on maintainability, and then optimize it where possible. Thank you.